# jquery validate textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate a textarea with jquery validate. I'm looking for regex to check multiple quoted strings separated by a whitespace and longer more than 5 chars.. :

"quoted text.." "some other quoted text" "another quoted string"  = good

"quoted text.." "" "another quoted string"  = not good

"quoted text.." "abcd" "another quoted string"  = not good

The following checks only the first quoted text ... ("quoted string longer than 5" ""   --> this passes but it shouldn't)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $.validator.addMethod("coll_regex", function(value, element) { 
   return this.optional(element) || /"(.*?)"/.test(value); 
    }, "Message here......");

$("#f_coll").validate(
{
    rules:{
    'coll_txt':{
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 200,
        coll_regex: true
        }
    },
    messages:{
    'coll_txt':{
        required: "Textarea is empty...",
        minlength: "Length must be, at least, 5 characters..",
        maxlength: "You exceeded the max_length !",
        coll_regex: "Use the quotes...."
       }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.next());
  }
});
});
```

is there a regex that does this ??? Would be great ... 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `/^("[^\".]{5,}" )*"[^\".]{5,}"$/`

```
'"abcdefg" "abcdefg" "01324"'.match(/^("[^\".]{5,}" )*"[^\".]{5,}"$/)  //--> true
'"abcdefg" "123" "01324"'.match(/^("[^\".]{5,}" )*"[^\".]{5,}"$/)  //--> false
'"abcdefg" "" "01324"'.match(/^("[^\".]{5,}" )*"[^\".]{5,}"$/)  //--> false
```

**EDIT:**

This one is more precise: `/^("[^\".]{5,}"\s+)*"[^\".]{5,}"$/`
It allows any whitespace between groups, not only a single space.

Comment: very good.. it works... however is there a way to have control on the max length (200) too in your regex?.. i think i will probably delete the maxlength method for my textarea validation 'cause it acts on the global length...  i appreciate thank you!

Comment: Sure! just add your value vor maxLength right behind the `{5,`. It reads like `{min,max}`. so it is `/^("[^\".]{5,200}" )*"[^\".]{5,200}"$/`